# Python MongoDB - Find_one user formatted string

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new to python and databases. I have successfully setup MongoDB with data from an excel sheet and can find data if I hard code the search queries.

I want to take user input as part of the db query, however I am struggling to get it to work. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
def db_bookout(stock_no):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://*****.mongodb.net/storedb?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    db=client["storedb"]
    collection = db["_stores"]  
    stock_details = collection.find_one({'Stock Number' : {}.format(stock_no)})
    for item in stock_details:
        pprint(item)


userinput = 'VEM007'
db_bookout(userinput)
```

also

```
    stock_details = collection.find_one({'Stock Number' : {stock_no}})
```

Hard coded, but works

```
 stock_details = collection.find_one({'Stock Number' : 'VEM007'})
```

Comment: You can just remove the curly braces and it should work fine: `stock_details = collection.find_one({'Stock Number' : stock_no})`

Comment: Thank you! It was that simple. I guess I got carried away using formatted strings on excel sheets this week. I'm trying to convert my excel book out program to using a database instead.